# CSS Flex: what's the most accurate way for making a grid-like layout?

Tags: css, layout, flexbox, grid

By design flex is (initially) a single lane of content and wasn't made specifically for grids.

I currently use `flex-wrap: wrap;` but it's not really made for making grids -- even though it's probably the first option you try to make one.

Moreover I think it's not the only way to create grid-like layouts.

So is this the most accurate (proper) way? of creating a grid in flex?

Or are there better alternatives?

Edit (after 2 answers were posted): just to clarify, I'm not looking for `display: grid;` I'm asking what is the most proper/accurate way of doing it in flex. (See [css flex grid](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/css/learn-css-flex-patterns-in-10-minutes))

(Of course `display: grid` is a proper way for making grids with CSS grid. That is **not** what the question is asking.)

Comment: answer is in the question and the tag you used: grid ! it won't take long to learn how to use it :)  gridbyexample.com/  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ it helps to start and have an overview.

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to go with `display: grid`.

> To get started you have to define a container element as a grid with
> display: grid, set the column and row sizes with grid-template-columns
> and grid-template-rows, and then place its child elements into the
> grid with grid-column and grid-row.

This is an useful post about https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

And this is a complete example:

The style:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

and the layout:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

so i came up with this its not perfect but you could tweak it to make it what you want i think...https://codepen.io/colinthedev/pen/ExKwVVZ

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "6vw";
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.flexWrapOne {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: inherit;
  margin: 0 .5rem 0 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.item1 {
  display: flex;
  order: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 20rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  background: #000;
}

.item2 {
  display: flex;
  order: 2;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  background: #0D89F2;
}

.item3 {
  display: flex;
  order: 3;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 15rem;
  width: 33rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  background: #89F20D;
}

.flexWrapTwo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 20rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  background: #000;
}

.item6 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: .5rem;
  background: #0D89F2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1430px) {
  .flexWrapTwo {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .item4 {
    order: 2;
  }
  
  .item6 {
    order: 1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
  .mainWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  .flexWrapOne {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: inherit;
  }
 
}
```

```html
<h1> Hello World!</h1>
<div class="flexWrapOne">
    <h1 class="item1"> ITEM-1 </h1>
    <h1 class="item2"> ITEM-2 </h1>
    <h1 class="item3"> ITEM-3 </h1>
</div>
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="flexWrapOne">
    <h1 class="item1"> ITEM-4 </h1>
    <h1 class="item2"> ITEM-5 </h1>
    <h1 class="item3"> ITEM-6 </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flexWrapTwo">
    <h1 class="item4"> ITEM-7 </h1>
    <h1 class="item6"> ITEM-8 </h1>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Same as above just copy pasted -->
<div class="flexWrapOne">
    <h1 class="item1"> ITEM-1 </h1>
    <h1 class="item2"> ITEM-2 </h1>
    <h1 class="item3"> ITEM-3 </h1>
</div>
<div class="mainWrapper">
  <div class="flexWrapOne">
    <h1 class="item1"> ITEM-4 </h1>
    <h1 class="item2"> ITEM-5 </h1>
    <h1 class="item3"> ITEM-6 </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="flexWrapTwo">
    <h1 class="item4"> ITEM-7 </h1>
    <h1 class="item6"> ITEM-8 </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```